# How to Add ILocalStorage and AuthenticationStateProvider in Customer Http DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am new to http requests and apis, I am trying to build a Maui Blazor App that uses JWT tokens along with a refreshToken. I was hoping to use a Http DelegatingHandler to check if the JWT has expired before the request is sent and if it is expired use the refresh token to get a new Jwt. Current I need to have a HttpClientHandler setup to by pass the https for development. Any advise would be helpful. Current setup below:

```
 public class HeaderInterceptor : DelegatingHandler

{
   public HeaderInterceptor() : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        
    }

    protected override  Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       // var token = _localStorageService.GetItemAsStringAsync("token");

        var innerHandler = InnerHandler;
        if (innerHandler is HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler)
        {
        
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };
            
        }
     
        try
        {
            ;


            request.Headers.Add("Custom-Header", "Customs");
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        

        return  base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
   public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseBarcodeReader()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });
      
        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
        builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiService, ApiService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<HeaderInterceptor>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped(
            sp => new HttpClient(new HeaderInterceptor()) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://192.168.6.115:7004/api/") }
            );
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();




        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```